# Control TI Launchpad over USB

Tags: msp430, launchpad

What's the easiest way to control a [TI Launchpad (MSP430)](http://e2e.ti.com/group/msp430launchpad/w/default.aspx) from Linux over USB? I just want to use the board to drive some LEDs while it's tethered to my computer, so I'm looking for a way to simply control the output pins via a TTY or mspdebug or similar. I don't have a crystal on my board yet, but can add one if needed.

Answer (score 3):

http://github.com/dwelch67/msp430_samples I use mspdebug to load programs.

I dont know if there is a communcation path between the target mcu and the host.  the mcu in the middle is the one you talk to and it uses spi by wire to load the target device.

I either bitbang or use the uart in the g2553 part to communicate with the host using a separate ftdi based usb to serial board (the kind used with 3.3v arduinos are super easy to come by, can also power the msp430 with this if you dont need to reprogram it.

Comment: well sure the debugger (mspdebug) can get through to the target, perhaps using that path you can hit addresses in the target's register space and fiddle with the I/O.  see what mspdebug offers from a command line, if possible then examine the mspdebug source to not have to make a program where you dont have to type the commands.

Comment: there are two flavors of launchpad kits one with the 2553 part, the other with a different set of parts none of which has a uart.

Answer (score 0):

The TI LaunchPad should show up as a USB serial device while in operation. You should be able to write a program that talks over this serial device with commands that you create in order to change your LED status. It might be easiest to start by making these serial commands human readable so that you can test them from a serial terminal program such PuTTY, Hyperterminal, minicom, etc.

Comment: Writing the program to talk over the serial device is left as an exercise to the reader?

Comment: The method of talking to the device over serial can be implemented in many different ways. If you have as existing program in which you want to add this functionality, you will want to look for serial libraries compatible with your language of choice that implement this. What language are you using?

Comment: I can use whatever language I need to. I was just asking if there were simpler solutions (or pre-made solutions) before I dive into implementing software UART.